# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException thrown after Attempted Execution of a Procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, t-sql

I am making a straightforward application using AngularJS and ASP.NET, which I am fairly new to. I created an SQL procedure but every time I have it executed, it throws the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'LoginProc' 
>   expects parameter '@IsValid', which was not supplied.'

How do I resolve this exception? Here is the code for storing the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE LoginProc
@username VARCHAR(50),
@password VARCHAR(MAX),
@IsValid bit out
AS
BEGIN
SET @IsValid=(SELECT COUNT(username) from "User" WHERE username=N'@username' and password=N'@password')
END
```

And here is the code that attempts to execute the procedure:

```
public class db
    {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["dbconnect"].ConnectionString);

        public int userlogin(User user)
        {
            int res;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoginProc", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (user.username != null && user.password != null) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.password);
                SqlParameter oblogin = new SqlParameter();
                oblogin.ParameterName = "@IsVaild";
                oblogin.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                oblogin.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(oblogin);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                res = Convert.ToInt32(oblogin.Value);
                con.Close();
            } 
            else
            {
                res = 0;
            }

            return res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code looks correct.  Are you sure a simple console app running that code produces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just mispelled @IsValid here:

```
oblogin.ParameterName = "@IsVaild";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Kind of a dumb bug but at least it will be easy to fix.